# Bootstrap successful alert in updating record Ajax

Tags: jquery, css, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, alert

I would like to use bootstrap alert in displaying success message in updating existing records. This is what I have:

**index.php**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#submit_button").click( function() {
          $.post( $("#updateunit").attr("action"), 
            $("#updateunit :input").serializeArray(),function(info){ 
              $("#result").html(info); 
          });
      });
      $("#updateunit").submit( function() {
          return false;   
      });
  });
  function clearInput() {
    $("#updateunit :input").each( function() {
      $(this).val('');
    });
}
```

```
<div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="transaction">Notes</label>
                <div class="controls">
                  <textarea rows="3" columns="10" name="notes"><?php echo $notes; ?></textarea>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                <button class="btn btn-custom" type="submit" id="submit_button">Update</button>
                <a href="#" class="back"><button class="btn btn-custom" onclick="goBack()">Back</button></a>
                </div>
              </div>

            </form>
            <div id="result" class="alert alert-success"></div>
          </div>
```

**edit.php**

```
  <?php
include('../../db.php');
if( isset($_POST['reservation_code']) || isset($_POST['transaction_code'])   ){
      $transaction_id = $_POST['transaction_id'];
      $reservation_code = $_POST['reservation_code'];
      $transaction_code = $_POST['transaction_code'];
      $notes = $_POST['notes'];

      $update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE tblunitreservation 
            SET reservation_code = :reservation_code,
            transaction_code = :transaction_code,
            notes = :notes
            WHERE transaction_id = :transaction_id");
      $update->execute(array(':reservation_code' => $reservation_code, 
                        ':transaction_code' => $transaction_code,
                        ':notes' => $notes,
                        ':transaction_id' => $transaction_id));
        echo 'Successfully updated record!';
} else {
        echo 'Required field/s is missing';
}
?>
```

I want the alert message to be in the centre of the screen but what happening is that when I do not update the record, the alert background is visible and then I update the record that is only the time the message Successfully update appears.

Comment: Check if either prepare or execute are failing

Comment: @HithamS.AlQadheeb it is already working, my problem is the displaying of alert

Comment: @user255798 This is a css issue, removing php tag.

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger what do you mean?

Comment: Are you using bootstrap version 2 or 3?

Comment: @ICanHasCheezburger I'm using 2.3.2 version of bootstrap

Answer (score 9):

If I got it right, you need two things:

1. Center the alert message.
2. Display the alert box only after button click.

For this you can omit adding the `alert` and `alert-success` class in the HTML itself. Change your HTML to (along with aligning of text):

```
<center><div id="result"></div></center>
```

Instead, we will add the class, once the text inside has been placed such as:

```
$("#submit_button").click( function() {
          $.post( $("#updateunit").attr("action"), 
            $("#updateunit :input").serializeArray(),function(info){ 
              $("#result").html(info); 
              //adding class
              $("#result").addClass("alert alert-success");
          });
      });
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g4aEt/1/)**

If you want the box to be centered too, make use of bootstrap classes:

```
 $("#result").addClass("alert alert-success offset4 span4");
```

Based on the [grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) of Bootstrap 2.3, you can have 12 columns, so to make the box center, we will leave 4 columns from the left which is what `offset4` does and make the length of the box to be 4 columns which is what `span4` does.

**[Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/g4aEt/2/)**

### Additional:

> what if I want to automatically close the alert message if it passes 5
>   seconds? and display the close button inside the alert message

For a smoother solution, you can do:

```
 //adding a 'x' button if the user wants to close manually
 $("#result").html('<div class="alert alert-success"><button type="button" class="close">×</button>'+info+'</div>');

 //timing the alert box to close after 5 seconds
 window.setTimeout(function () {
     $(".alert").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function () {
         $(this).remove();
     });
 }, 5000);

 //Adding a click event to the 'x' button to close immediately
 $('.alert .close').on("click", function (e) {
     $(this).parent().fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500);
 });
```

**[Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/g4aEt/7/)**

Comment: Thanks for this, but what if I want to automatically close the alert message if it passes 5 seconds? and display the close button inside the alert message

Comment: Brilliantly answered.

Comment: really like this, but what if the user submits several requests and I want to request an alert for each?