# Ajax Post Data and return with error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

i currently have the code below that submits form data from a bunch of dynamic forms this is working well and is returning a notification with a success or failure and inserting it into the div #info however when the error or success is shown on the page the only way to get rid of the notification is to refresh or navigate to another page

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('submit', 'form.frm_details', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/limitless/functions2.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.status == '1') {
                        $('#info').addClass('alert alert-success alert-styled-left alert-arrow-left alert-bordered').html(data.message);
                        $('.my-modals').modal('hide');
                        document.getElementById('frm_details0').reset();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

so my question is how can i make it so you click a link or a an x button on the right hand side of the notification window to close the or hide the div

i have attached a picture copy of the notification window  and the only code on the page besides the script below is

[image]

Comment: You can use setTimeout( function(){$('#info').hide();} , 3000);

Comment: Firstly don't use ID's use classe's, sometimes it's a good idea to prepend with "js-" at least you know which is for javascript and which is for styling. Why not just add a click event to hide/fade the notification box?

Comment: Yes it's just info <div id='info'><div> and I have provided everything the notification is created via in the script above and displayed on the page as the info div

Comment: $('.js-info').click(function(){ $(this).hide() }); this would work click the div, if you want an anchor click then: $(this).parent().hide();

Comment: @TezWingfield this is exactly what im hoping for how could i implement this using the same method as above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Per comments:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
        $(document).on('submit', 'form.frm_details', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                url: '/limitless/functions2.php',
                type: 'post',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.status == '1') {
                        $('#info').addClass('alert alert-success alert-styled-left alert-arrow-left alert-bordered').html(data.message);
                        $('.my-modals').modal('hide');
                        document.getElementById('frm_details0').reset();
                    }
                }
            });
        });
      //preferably anchor tag
      $('.some-close-element').click(function(e)
      {
         e.preventDefault();
         $(this).parent().hide();
      });
    });
</script>
```

This makes the assumption your adding an anchor tag inside info alert box which ultimately closes the alert box.

Comment: what changes need to be made to the div to get this to work

Comment: after modifying ur code           $('#info').click(function(e)
          {
          $(this).hide();
          });  this hides the notifications div is there anyway to shorten the code

Comment: I suppose there are a couple of possibilities but require slight restructuring... In all honesty you're applying an event handler, it's very readable and it's about 60 characters - no need to obfuscate the logic. You can remove the event (e). To note you can use: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to help with refactoring logic.

Comment: after much consideration and testing this method hides the event for the rest of the session then any other events are not shown so this method doesn't work for me but is what i originally asked for

Comment: added my answer to this question but thanks for your time u pointed me in the direction which led me to the answer

Comment: @Nathan Could you award the answer to the user that correctly answered the original question...

Answer (score 0):

You can hide notification after some time interval on get response from ajax:

```
  if (data.status == '1') {
        $('#info').addClass('alert alert-success alert-styled-left alert-arrow-left alert-bordered').html(data.message);
        setTimeout( function(){
           $('#info').hide();} , 
        3000); 
        //or                                                                                
            $("#info").delay(4000).hide();
            $('.my-modals').modal('hide');
            document.getElementById('frm_details0').reset();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After more research on this site i was going about the alerts all wrong i should be dismissing the alert as per the discussion here

[Bootstrap successful alert in updating record Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22679575/bootstrap-successful-alert-in-updating-record-ajax)

however after thoroughly reading my and trial and error my solution is the below

```
    $('#info').html('<div class="alert alert-danger alert-styled-left alert-arrow-left alert-bordered">'  + data.message + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" >×</button></div>');
```